# Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::isScopeActive()

Tags: php, symfony

Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::isScopeActive()

I have a BlogBundle with Symfony3, there is no such issue in index page, but occurred on 'show post page'.

Can you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Controller

```
    /**
 * @Route("/post/{slug}", name="blog_post")
 * @Template()
 */
public function postAction(Post $post)
{
    return [
        'post' => $post,
    ];
}
```

var/cache/dev/classes.php

```
    namespace Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle
{
    use Assetic\ValueSupplierInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    class DefaultValueSupplier implements ValueSupplierInterface
    {
        protected $container;
        public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
        }
        public function getValues()
        {
            if (!$this->container->isScopeActive('request')) {
                return array();
            }
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            return array('locale'=> $request->getLocale(),'env'=> $this->container->getParameter('kernel.environment'),
            );
        }
    }
}
```

traced on line 7368:`if (!$this->container->isScopeActive('request')) {`

logs:

```
    INFO - Matched route "blog_post".
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.subject AS subject_2, t0.slug AS slug_3, t0.summary AS summary_4, t0.content AS content_5, t0.picture_url AS picture_url_6, t0.created_at AS created_at_7, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_8, t0.user_id AS user_id_9, t0.category_id AS category_id_10 FROM posts t0 WHERE t0.slug = ? LIMIT 1 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_4, t0.parent_id AS parent_id_5 FROM categories t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_4 FROM tags t0 INNER JOIN post_tags ON t0.id = post_tags.post_id WHERE post_tags.tag_id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.content AS content_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_4, t0.user_id AS user_id_5, t0.post_id AS post_id_6 FROM comments t0 WHERE t0.post_id = ? ORDER BY t0.created_at DESC 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.roles AS roles_5, t0.created_at AS created_at_6, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_7 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
CRITICAL - Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::isScopeActive() in /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php:7368 Stack trace: #0 /Users/heaven/web/blog/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/ValueContainer.php(76): Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DefaultValueSupplier->getValues() #1 /Users/heaven/web/blog/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/ValueContainer.php(61): Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer->initialize() #2 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4984): Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer->getIterator() #3 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Object(Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer)) #4 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Array) #5 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Array) #6 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/clas 
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::isScopeActive() in /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php:7368 Stack trace: #0 /Users/heaven/web/blog/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/ValueContainer.php(76): Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DefaultValueSupplier->getValues() #1 /Users/heaven/web/blog/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/ValueContainer.php(61): Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer->initialize() #2 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4984): Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer->getIterator() #3 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Object(Assetic\Extension\Twig\ValueContainer)) #4 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Array) #5 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php(4989): Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter->normalize(Array) #6 /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/clas" at /Users/heaven/web/blog/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7368 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Comment: Please add your relevant code to your question.

Comment: When asked to post code the intent is to edit your question.  Not to add answers.  In any event, scope has been removed in Symfony 3.  One of your bundles need updating.  It almost seems like you never cleared your cache,

Comment: Thanks, I have update the question.
I have done the `composer update` and clear the cache, but the issue still occurs.

Comment: try physically remove the cache via `rm -rf var/cache/*`

Comment: Your composer.json is messed up.  Somehow you are loading an earlier version of the dependency injection component.  You simply should not have an isScopeActive method at all.  Create a fresh Symfony 3 project then install one bundle at a time until you get the error.  Be aware that many 3rd party bundles are not yet S3 compatible.  You may end up rolling back to S2.8.

Comment: In my case, the problem was cause by `KnpMenuBundle`. Once I've updated my `composer.json` to require the proper version everything worked fine.

Comment: in my case, strangely enough, I was referring to a method that was undefined. (getMyMethod() did not exist and was actually myMethod()).